# To allow multi select in Rhandsontable column dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, shiny, multi-select, handsontable, rhandsontable

I am trying to build a application in R shiny, where I am using a handsontable to take inputs from users. One column in my handsontable is having dropdowns where I need multiple selection from the user.

For example in my below sample code, I want to allow user to select multiple values in 'big' column (i.e. user should be able to select A,B,C for first row and likewise for other rows)

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             sliderInput('input', label = "Rows",
                         min = 1, max = nrow(iris), value = 10)
      ),

      column(12
             ,
             rHandsontableOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    DF = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                    small = letters[1:10],
                    dt = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    # try updating big to a value not in the dropdown
    output$table <- renderRHandsontable(
      rhandsontable(DF, rowHeaders = NULL, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
        hot_col(col = "big", type = "dropdown", source = LETTERS) %>%
        hot_col(col = "small", type = "autocomplete", source = letters,
                strict = FALSE)
    )
  }
)
```

Let me know if anyone has faced the same problem and resolved the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing for me, you want that the slider reacts to how many selected options do the user put or...?

Then I don't know why you put max = nrow(iris) if you are not using the iris dataframe, that makes no sense.

Finally if you want to have a reactive UI so when the user put something, the ui change, you will need this:

1- The reactive function for server:

```
`outSli <- reactive({
 ##here you put your action
 })`
```

2- The observe function for server to change the ui slider:

```
`observe({
 ##here you put the outSli() that contains your action or algorithm and then you update the slider
 updateSliderInput(session, "input", label = NULL, value = NULL,
  min = NULL, max = NULL, step = NULL)
 ##all those NULLs is what you change with your outSli()
 })`
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply and apologies for the confusion!! Actually, problem has nothing to do with the slider, I just want users to be able to select multiple values in dropdown. For example, In my sample code, I want to allow user to select multiple values in 'big' column (i.e. user should be able to select A,B,C for first row and likewise for other rows).

Comment: For that i think you will need to do html and css

Comment: Yeah, I guess so!! But not sure, how do I overwrite the existing property of Rhandsontable. May be someone else might have better idea. Hoping to get something from stackoverflow users.